# Viewing every comment posted to my questions

Tags: support, profile-page

I'm afraid that I'm missing comments that are being posted to questions that I've asked weeks/months ago.

Is there any way that I can see which comments I haven't touched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your profile, go to the tab marked **Responses.** That should give you a good idea. It's all ordered chronologically. Your profile responses [are here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111665/pedro?tab=responses).

Answer (score 2):

All user responses to your comments and posts are [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111665/pedro?tab=responses)